# update all the records in table not a single record

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and working on a codeignter project where i have to update the user record. The id and data of user passed to model are correct, but when i update the record, all the users are updated with the new record. My coding is :

```
public function updateUser(){
    $user = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $userID = $user['id'];
    $data = array(
                                "first_name"        =>      $this->input->post('reg_first_name'),
                                "last_name"     =>      $this->input->post('reg_last_name'),
                                "mobile"            =>      $this->input->post('reg_mobile'),
                                "country"   =>      $this->input->post('reg_country'),
                                "state"     =>      $this->input->post('reg_state'),
                                "city"      =>      $this->input->post('reg_city'),
                                "paypal_email"  =>      ''
                        );

    $this->db->update('users',$data);
    $this->db->where('id',$userID);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){

            return true;    
        }
        else {
            return false;  
        } 


    }
```

Is there something wrong in my code, Please help.

Comment: I am surprised that there is no validation in your code.

Comment: where statement should be first than update statement. so your code should like this: $this->db->where('id',$userID); then $this->db->update('users',$data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
public function updateUser(){
$user = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$userID = $user['id'];
$data = array(
                            "first_name"        =>      $this->input->post('reg_first_name'),
                            "last_name"     =>      $this->input->post('reg_last_name'),
                            "mobile"            =>      $this->input->post('reg_mobile'),
                            "country"   =>      $this->input->post('reg_country'),
                            "state"     =>      $this->input->post('reg_state'),
                            "city"      =>      $this->input->post('reg_city'),
                            "paypal_email"  =>      ''
                    );
$this->db->where('id',$userID);    //changes here  where clause should be provided before update
$this->db->update('users',$data);
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){

        return true;    
    }
    else {
        return false;  
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

yours looks fine but the only problem is... you are updating your DB first and adding where to it..which is not how it should be where should be before the update query.

```
 $this->db->where('id',$userID);
 $this->db->update('users',$data);
```